# How to get Bokeh's 'PointDrawTool' working with a NetworkX Spring_Layout

Tags: python, bokeh, networkx

I am working on a network node graph using NetworkX and Bokeh. I am using NetworkX's spring_layout to automatically generate positions for each of my nodes. However, I cannot figure out how to drag the nodes around on my graph (and also have the edges follow along with any dragged nodes).

How do I enable node-dragging for my NetworkX/Bokeh graph?

I have tried using Bokeh's 'PointDrawTool' tool, however, even though the tool renders and shows up in the toolbar next to my graph, it isn't functional.

```
plot = Plot(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000,
            x_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1,1.1))


plot.title.text = "Network Graph"

graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout)

plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("ID", "@index"), ("Internal IP", "@Internal")]), PointDrawTool(renderers = [graph_renderer.node_renderer], empty_value = 'black'), TapTool(), BoxSelectTool(), BoxEditTool(), BoxZoomTool(), PanTool(), WheelZoomTool(), ZoomInTool(), ZoomOutTool(), SaveTool(), UndoTool())

graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=10, fill_color=Spectral4[0])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph = Circle(size=10, fill_color=Spectral4[2])
graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph = Circle(size=10, fill_color=Spectral4[1])

graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="#CCCCCC", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[2], line_width=3)
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph = MultiLine(line_color=Spectral4[1], line_width=3)

graph_renderer.selection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()
graph_renderer.inspection_policy = NodesAndLinkedEdges()

plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

output_file("interactive_graphs.html")
show(plot)
```

I expect the nodes to be draggable. I want to click on a node and drag it so that it changes its position.

**14/05/2019 Edit:**
My imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, HoverTool, TapTool, BoxEditTool, BoxSelectTool, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, ZoomInTool, ZoomOutTool, SaveTool, UndoTool, PointDrawTool
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx, NodesAndLinkedEdges, EdgesAndLinkedNodes
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

from IPython.display import display, HTML
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
```

Comment: Can you add your imports block of code? It is unclear how exactly you imported `bokeh` submodules.

Comment: @vumux I've updated my post with all my imports.

Comment: I have never used Bokeh much, but there is no indication in [their demo](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html) that they have implemented the necessary logic for dragging nodes around. I don't know how set you are on using Bokeh, but I have written a small graph visualization library that does support dragging of nodes and edges. It's called `netgraph` and you can find it [here](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). Would love to hear your feedback, especially if it doesn't fit your needs. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/networkx-import-and-pointdrawtool/3512

```
"The proximate cause of the problem is that the tool requires access to
 glyph.x.field and glyph.y.field but both of these are null for the Circle node
 renderer. The GraphRenderer is the only example of a “composite” renderer, so it’s
 entirely possible (probable) that there is some interaction problem specific to it
 with the PointDrawTool. The next appropriate step would be to make a bug report
 issue on GitHub 5 with details."
```

It would be nice if they solved it.

Comment: Can you please post sample code for better understanding.